# Dart - How can I Map String & Int together?

Tags: dart, flutter

```
static Future<String> compress({@required String imageSrc, @required int desiredQuality}) async {
  final Map<String, dynamic> params = <String, dynamic> {
   'filePath': imageSrc.toString()
  };
```

I'm trying to add `desiredQuality` on the "params" map, but that's an int, how can I do it?

EDIT:

Turns out I didn't need to map int, all I had to do was this:

```
static Future<String> compress({@required String imageSrc, @required int desiredQuality}) async {
  final Map<String, dynamic> params = <String, dynamic> {
   'filePath': imageSrc,
   'desiredQuality': desiredQuality
  };
```

Thanks to @MarcG and @Gunter

Comment: Add where? And what do you want to return?

Comment: I'm trying to pass on the value of `desiredQuality` into the iOS and Android native code. Right now, the only param going through is filePath, now I need desiredQuality and that's it.

Comment: Your code should work, except when `imageSrc` is `null`. You can use `imageSrc?.toString()` to work around that

Comment: imageSrc is already a String. No need to do imageSrc.toString();

Comment: Do you mean this? final Map<String, dynamic> params = <String, dynamic>{'filePath': imageSrc, 'desiredQuality': desiredQuality };

Comment: Besides you are returning nothing, and you can't return params as a Future<String>. You could return a Future<Map<String, dynamic>>, if that's what you want.

Comment: Also if you need you can convert an int to a String like so: desiredQuality.toString()

Comment: I don't need it to convert to string, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A [Map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Map-class.html) object could contain a collection of key/value pairs. Since you're trying to assign `imageSrc` (String) and `desiredQuality` (int) values on a `Map<String, dynamic>`, you can assign keys for each of these values in the Map.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> params = {
  'filePath': imageSrc,
  'desiredQuality': desiredQuality
};
```

To access these key/values set in the Map, you can call them using:

```dart
var filePath = params['filePath'];
var desiredQuality = params['desiredQuality'];
```